# MYSQL Count unique rows on Where then Left Join and Sort by that count and then Limit to 3

Tags: mysql, sorting, count, left-join, where-clause

I have two tables; one with columns Text, Topic, User called 'Messages Table' and the other table has columns Topic, Title called 'Topic Table'.

Example:

**Messages Table**

```
Text        Topic    User
Hi          Ball     Hank
Hello       Foot     John
Sup         Ball     Hank
Nuthin'     Foot     Hank
No          Volley   Hank
```

**Topic Table**

```
Topic     Title
Ball      Basketball
Foot      Football
Volley    Volleyball
```

I want to display a user's top three favorite topics with the topic Title.

**Result: Hank's Top 3 Topics**

```
Topic Count     Topic      Title
2               Ball       Basketball
1               Foot       Football
1               Volley     Volleyball
```

I have to COUNT the unique Topics the specific user has in the 'Messages Table', then join it to the 'Topic Table' so I can grab the Title, and then order the result by the count of Topics in descending order so I can get the user's most used topic. And then limit the result to 3 rows just to get the top 3.

Help.

Comment: Show your tables layout, preferably using CREATE TABLE syntax. It would be nice if you could give some example data, with your expected output. Most helpful and easiest for us and for you is to create example on http://SQLFiddle.com and post a link to it.

Comment: Done. Basic-basic example but it's the gist. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need TOP-3 topics only for Hank try

```sql
SELECT COUNT(m.Topic) `Count Topic`, m.Topic, MIN(t.Title) Title
  FROM messages m LEFT JOIN
       topics t ON m.Topic = t.Topic 
WHERE User = 'Hank'
GROUP BY m.Topic 
ORDER BY `Count Topic` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Output:

```
| COUNT TOPIC |  TOPIC |      TITLE |
-------------------------------------
|           2 |   Ball | Basketball |
|           1 |   Foot |   Football |
|           1 | Volley | Volleyball |
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46e3a/7)**

Comment: Awesome. And does this sort COUNT by descending order and limit the output to 3 rows?

Comment: @tomuky See updated answer. I simplified the query a bit. Outer select was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your query, you're searching for Hank?  If so, this should work using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Count(m.Topic), t.topic, t.title
FROM messages m
   JOIN topic t on m.topic=t.topic
WHERE m.user = 'Hank'
GROUP BY t.topic
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75d6e/3)

**--EDIT--**

```
SELECT user, cnt, topic, title
FROM (
  SELECT 
    @rowNum:=IF(@prevUser=m.user,@rowNum+1,1) rn,
    @prevUser:=m.user,
    m.cnt, 
    t.topic, 
    t.title, 
    m.user
  FROM (SELECT Count(Topic) cnt, topic, user FROM messages GROUP BY user, topic ORDER BY user, Count(Topic) DESC) m
     JOIN topic t on m.topic=t.topic
     JOIN (SELECT @rowNum:= 0) t
  ) t
WHERE RN <= 3
ORDER BY User
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac052/1)

This should return 3 records for each user -- if you want just a single user, add to the WHERE clause.

Comment: This works. But what about sorting by COUNT descending and limiting to 3?

Comment: Other answer was more directed to my exact need. Your version is more powerful and could be useful in other areas of my website. Thanks!

Comment: @tomuky -- no worries, glad we could help!